# Wikipedia API how to use it to edit content

Tags: php, api, wiki, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have a problem, someone sabotaged some pages on Wikipedia by redacting content.
Is it possible to check the specific paragraph that content was changed in and restore it?

Comment: Having a robot to automatically restore content is very much frowned apon and will probably get you blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question. But as the title shows, you may want to edit a wiki page via API. so... this may help you:

```
$page = new Article(Title::newFromText('PageName'));
$status = $page->doEdit($body_text, 'message.', EDIT_UPDATE);
```

And if you want to revert to a prior revision of an article, you may read the docs about [Rollback API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aRollback) of Mediawiki.